# Twitter Bootstrap nav-bar overlapping Drupal Admin bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, overlapping

I'm working on a site using Drupal 7 and Twitter Bootstrap. I have a navigation bar on top of my page.
When I log in as admin in Drupal, the admin bar appears. These 2 navigation bars overlap each other.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I prevent this? I want the Twitter nav-bar always on top of my page, but when I'm logged in on Drupal I want it to be below the Drupal bar.

Answer (score 0):

you have probably used navbar-fixed-top in your navbar.  if so you can try removing it.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

alternatively you can put in navbar-fixed-bottom and it will stick your bootstrap navbar to the bottom of the screen.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top { top: 0px; }
body.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top { top: 28px !important; }
```

if that does work for you (which it should!), then you'll have to move the  wp admin bar to the bottom by sticking the code below into a plugins folder or your functions.php file:

```
function fb_move_admin_bar() {
    echo '
    <style type="text/css">
    body { 
    margin-top: -28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    body.admin-bar #wphead {
       padding-top: 0;
    }
    body.admin-bar #footer {
       padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    #wpadminbar {
        top: auto !important;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul {
        bottom: 28px;
    }
    </style>';
}
// on backend area
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
// on frontend area
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
```

as an alternative you can use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stick-admin-bar-to-bottom/)

Comment: The op is using Drupal not Wordpress.